# Table2 can't accept references from the table 1 - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Can't figure this out. Why the table2 can't accept references from the table 1? Help please..

```
--table1--
CREATE TABLE table1(
t1_1 NUMBER(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
t1_2 VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
t1_3 NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL);

--table2--
CREATE TABLE table2(
t2_1 NUMBER(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
t1_1 REFERENCES table1(t1_1),
t1_3 REFERENCES table1(t1_3),
t2_datum DATE NOT NULL);
```

ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Comment: A foreign key must reference a key (either a primary key or a unique constraint.) Just what the error message says...

Comment: BTW, don't you mean "why table2 can't reference table1"?

Comment: Isn't table2 already referencing PK from the table 1?

Comment: The offending line is `t1_3 REFERENCES table1(t1_3)`. This line is trying to reference `t1_3`, but that's not a *key*.

Answer (score 1):

If your business logic approve then make column `t1_3` of `table1` unique. Your problem will be resolved.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
t1_1 NUMBER(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
t1_2 VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
t1_3 NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL unique);

--table2--
CREATE TABLE table2(
t2_1 NUMBER(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
t1_1 REFERENCES table1(t1_1),
t1_3 REFERENCES table1(t1_3),
t2_datum DATE NOT NULL);
```

If t1_3 can't be made unique then you can create composite unique key constraint on t1_1 and t1_3 then create composite foreign key as below:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
t1_1 NUMBER(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
t1_2 VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
t1_3 NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL ,
constraint uk_1_3 unique (t1_1,t1_3));

--table2--
CREATE TABLE table2(
t2_1 NUMBER(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
t1_1 REFERENCES table1(t1_1),
t1_3,
t2_datum DATE NOT NULL,
constraint fk_1_3 FOREIGN KEY(t1_1,t1_3) 
references table1(t1_1,t1_3));
```

Comment: That's the thing that the value can't be unique. Is there some other solution?

Comment: If the value is not unique then how could you relate both tables based on that? How could you know which row of table1 is being referenced by a value of t1_3 column of table2? Or it will be a composite key combining t1_1 and t1_3?

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks!